# C++/CLI Enquiry

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Currently the company I work for are implementing a new Graphical User Interface for all their software. The new GUI will be implemented in WPF which requires a lot of our old software to interoperate with the .NET Framework. I recently have been assigned the duty of implementing a WPF interface for software that is written in native C++.

I have decided to implement a wrapper within C++/CLI which will wrap around the native C++ code. The functionality obtained by the wrapper will then be used within C#.

The problem I have is that whenever I reference a header file (which resides within the native C++ project) from the C++/CLI project, I am met with many errors (See below). This is a problem because the native code compiles with no errors when the project is built standalone.

```
2>C:\Users\ABGZAMANK\Music\15.02.2013\DeskUpdate\Dev\Source\Libraries\DeskUpdateCore.dll\Sources\FileOperation.h(16): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'DWORD'
2>C:\Users\ABGZAMANK\Music\15.02.2013\DeskUpdate\Dev\Source\Libraries\DeskUpdateCore.dll\Sources\FileOperation.h(17): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CAtlString'
2>C:\Users\ABGZAMANK\Music\15.02.2013\DeskUpdate\Dev\Source\Libraries\DeskUpdateCore.dll\Sources\FileOperation.h(17): error C2535: 'CFExeption::CFExeption(void)' : member function already defined or declared
2>          C:\Users\ABGZAMANK\Music\15.02.2013\DeskUpdate\Dev\Source\Libraries\DeskUpdateCore.dll\Sources\FileOperation.h(16) : see declaration of 'CFExeption::CFExeption'
2>C:\Users\ABGZAMANK\Music\15.02.2013\DeskUpdate\Dev\Source\Libraries\DeskUpdateCore.dll\Sources\FileOperation.h(18): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetErrorText'
2>C:\Users\ABGZAMANK\Music\15.02.2013\DeskUpdate\Dev\Source\Libraries\DeskUpdateCore.dll\Sources\FileOperation.h(18): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

etc...

1. Is native C++ fully compatible with C++/CLI or will changes need to be made to the native C++ code?
2. Is their a more adequate approach to this task?
3. If you have a solution to the error messages or any advice, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's complaining about `DWORD` not being defined, it's likely that you're missing the windows headers. Try adding `#include <windows.h>` before you include the headers for your library. (Or modify FileOperation.h to include windows.h itself.)

In answer to 'Is native C++ fully compatible with C++/CLI?', the answer is 'mostly'. Where you'll run into problems is if you have something defined in C++ that is a language keyword in C++/CLI. For example, `int gcnew = 1` is perfectly valid C++, but won't work at all in C++/CLI, since `gcnew` is a keyword. In general, though, you should be OK.

From your question, it sounds like you're taking all of the C++ code, and compiling it into the C++/CLI project. If this is an existing tested library, another option is to keep the C++ code as an unmanaged DLL, and call to the unmanaged DLL from C++/CLI, rather than shoving it together in the same project. That said, my preference would be to do what it appears you're doing, compiling the C++ code into the managed assembly.